# Dynamic forms using Zend Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-sub-form, dynamicform

Hi guys I'm building a contacts application using the Zend Framework 1. I have a contacts table and a contact_data table.

```
Contact
|NAME|DESCRIPTION|...

CONTACT DATA
|TYPE|LOCATION|DETAILS|CONTACT_ID

ADDRESS
STREET|ZIP|CITY|STATE|COUNTRY|CONTACT_ID
```

The Contact Data holds all contact details such as Phone, Email, Fax etc and the address table is self explanatory. The trick is that I need to set it up so that I can add unlimited contact data and addresses. I've accomplished this earlier on by pretty much working on customised views however thats putting a lot of code logic within the view which I don't want. So I'm redoing it using Zend_Form but am stuck with regards to setting up the add/edit/remove multiple contact details from the same form part.

I have the javascript worked out and know how to get it done using views - but I need to get this done using Zend Forms here. I've looked at the idea of subforms however in my case I need to do the following:

My form is stuctured as follows:

Text and INputs for all contact details listed out

A special contact Data region with links to Add a Phone, Add a Fax, Add an address. Clicking on these links would open up and add a set of inputs to the table eg add an address link adds a street, city, country and state set of input to the table.

I've been hacking at this for an hour and am pretty lost here. Any ideas on how can i handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this problem is creating new Elements. One for contact data and one for address. Each of those elements should have custom viewHelper to render your complex interface. Each of view helpers can assign javascript file to handle dynamic adding / removing.

```
class Form_Element_Contact extends Zend_Form_Element_Xhtml {

    public $helper = 'contact';

}

class Zend_View_Helper_Contact extends Zend_View_Helper_FormElement {

    public function contact($name, $value = null, $attribs = null, $options = null) {
        $this->view->headScript()->appendFile("/js/dynamicInterfaceForContacts.js");
        $info = $this->_getInfo($name, $value, $attribs, $options);

        $html = $this->generateHtml(); // elements should be part of an array
        return $html;
    }

}
```

If you need more details let me know.

Comment: I get that - the only question is how do I set up my form using Zend_Form so that I can create multiple contact data elements and addresses. Basically I want to click on an Add new Phone, or Add new Fax and via javascript append the elements. I have the javascript part set out but how do I set up the form - and that too such that when I edit I view all the contact details...

Comment: The trick is in form element names. You have to use multidimensional arrays. As you said you can easily create dynamic interface in JS but form has to be also rebuild by PHP. With an array you can iterate through all values in the view helper. You will have something like: contact[set1][type], contact[set1][location], ...

Comment: So how would that be exhibited in code using Zend_Form? I don't want to put this logic in the view but don't know how to set it using Zend_Form

Comment: $value inside the view helper will hold the array with all "subelements" values. If you don't like keeping all that logic inside the helper you can do it in form. The problem is you don't know what elements / subforms should be there until you populate(), setDefaults() or isValid() the form. In other words you can't do it in init() method. If you want to reuse Zend elements you need to be sure you can capture all possible ways the form can be feed with data. This is why it's easier to do it in view because at render time the data will be already there.